# How should it hide the implementations of certain functions in different classes

Tags: c++

Sorry for my English. I have a File class that has two virtual methods read and save. This class is inherited by two FileServer FileClient classes. I would like , for example, class A will have only write functions and class B will have only read functions. I don't know if I solved this problem well in my example code.And I am also wondering how should I name the Menager class and FileApi class.

```
class FileApi
{
public:
    virtual bool read() = 0;
    virtual bool save() = 0;
};

class FileServerApi : public FileApi
{
public:
    bool read() override
    {
        return false;
    }
    bool save() override
    {
        return false;
     }
};

class FileClientApi : public FileApi
{
public:
    bool read() override
    {
        return false;
    }
    bool save() override
    {
        return false;
    }
};

class Menager
{
public:
    bool read()
    {
        return m_FileApi->read();
    }
    bool save()
    {
        return m_FileApi->save();
    }
    FileApi* m_FileApi;
};

class Recipient : protected Menager
{
public:
    Menager::read;
};

class Sender : protected Menager
{
public:
    Menager::save;
};
```

This code prevents me from accessing other functions, such as the FileServer class, which is a bit of a handicap for me

Comment: If the classes do different things, perhaps they should not have a common base class. There is no language requirement for classes to derive from an interface declaration.

Comment: You could also inherit from two base classes. One that reads and one that writes. See the inheritance graph for [`basic_ifstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream) for example.

Comment: Hmm, your `Menager` class contain a raw pointer at `FileApi* m_FileApi;`: you will have a non default dtor, and by the rule of 5 non default copy/move ctors/assignment operators...

Comment: You could make the functions you don't want `public` in your derived classes `private` - that would prevent users of those classes from calling them. Just because they are public in the base class doesn't mean you have to make them public in the derived classes (or maybe they should be `protected` in the base class and then you can selectively make them `public` in the derived ones)?

Comment: The classes have common interfaces because I want them to work on common bases, e.g. priority queue, etc. If I were to divide the interfaces, I would have to pass the object of this data via reference or pointer. Probably the simplest solution is to use something like basic_ifstream with protected inheritance